# Android finish activity from another class

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to finish activity from another class, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.project.myapp.Link_holder cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

First in activity I call method that turning in class where I want to finish activity. For closing I using this code:

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Activity:

```
element.createSubmitButton(this, reviewsLayout, objJson, elementList,
                objectID, exists, user, realLink, mDialog);
```

Element class:

```
  Data_synch x = new Data_synch(realLink, context.getApplicationContext(), user, mDialog);
x.run();
```

Data_synch class:

```
new SyncFromServer(realLink, false, false, false, true, user, mContext, mDialog);
```

SyncFromServer class:

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Comment: What is `Link_holder`? Where is context initialized

Comment: it means that Link_holder is not an Activity.

Comment: edited, please let`s see

Answer (score 0):

When trying to get the activity in a class use `getActivity().finish();` or `((MainActivity)getActivity()).finish();`. In which **MainActivity** is what ever you named the **MainActivity** when you created your project.